# How to make a DVD movie of my photos?

Tags: dvd, slideshow

I want to make a slide show out of my photos, burn this slide-show to a DVD as a movie that can be played on a regular old DVD player.  Suprisingly, I am finding this difficult to achieve.  All the programs I've seen want to burn either onto a CD or a program that is runnable on a PC.

Suggestions?

Comment: Somewhere there's a family member that hopes this question is never answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best software there is for this task:

> **[MemoriesOnTV](http://www.codejam.com/products.htm)** is our award-winning photo/video slideshow software. This
>   feature-packed program comes with
>   beautiful and elegant pre-built
>   effects that you can use. In
>   addition, the powerful and advanced
>   features and tools allow you to craft
>   your slideshows any way you want. Let
>   your creativity flow with
>   MemoriesOnTV!

Output: **DVD**, Web, AVI or MPG

[image]

*MemoriesOnTV is shareware, try before you buy.*

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, here are two products you might use to create an movie file from your photos:

[Foto2Avi](http://www.trustfm.net/divx/SoftwareFoto2Avi.php?b2=1)

> Foto2Avi is a freeware video/photo
>   converter to avi/mpeg/flv. It is an
>   video editor too. Has thousands of
>   special effects like Transitions
>   (Flippage,Swirl...), Basic Effects
>   (Brightness/Noise/Fade in/Fade out),
>   Advanced Effects (Distort, Ripple),
>   Animations, Subtitles, Logos.   It
>   support external audio sounds
>   [mp3/ogg/wav] and can trim audio video
>   streams, so you can edit your sounds
>   synchronized with your videos. You can
>   save your work in *.f2a project files
>   and reload later.

[Slide Show Movie Maker](http://www.joern-thiemann.de/) :

> Slide Show Movie Maker can create an
>   .avi vide slideshow from a series of
>   .bmp or .jpg images. Images can have
>   professional-looking fade-in and
>   fade-out effects, plus attractive text
>   overlays.

Then use [Avi2Dvd](http://www.trustfm.net/divx/SoftwareAvi2Dvd.php?b2=1) to convert the .avi to DVD:

> Avi2Dvd - converts with one click an
>   AVI / OGM / MKV / DVD to DVD / SVCD /
>   VCD. Uses only freeware software.
>   Supports: VideoStream, AudioStream,
>   Subtitle Streams (in DVD mode)

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm sure there's software out there that can do it all automatically, you can find instructions on how to manually create a slideshow video at [this link](http://linuxgazette.net/153/bhaaluu.html).  The instructions are linux-specific, but I'm sure the specified software (or equivalents) are available for Windows/MacOS/Whatever that can do the same thing.

A quick summary to protect against link death:

1. Take all the images you want to slideshow

   - Convert/stretch/shrink/pad them to 320x200 resolution
   - Higher resolutions should be possible, but I've not tested this
   - Save images in uncompressed .ppm for best results
2. Copy them over and over and over and over again

   - Name these something like frame0001 frame0002 ... frame9999
   - You'll want 25 frames for each second of video
   - Fades and transitions are possible with clever scripting and [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php)
3. Use [mpeg2encode](http://www.mpeg.org/MPEG/video/mssg-free-mpeg-software.html) to turn these into an mpeg video
4. Optionally create a sound file to play over the slideshow

   - Use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to combine the video and audio tracks
5. Enjoy your new video. (Yay!)

After that, you'll probably have much better luck burning a normal mpg video to DVD with your software of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what OS you're using, but there is a linux script called '[dvd-slideshow](http://dvd-slideshow.sourceforge.net/wiki/Main_Page)'.  It takes a text file of instructions as input, but allows for the easy addition of images, title slides, transition effects and multiple audio tracks.  The text file format is basic.  1 command per line, `#` lines are  comments.

There is a related too called [dir2slideshow](http://dvd-slideshow.sourceforge.net/wiki/Dir2slideshow_0.8.0).  If you want to make a quick & dirty dvd of all the images in a directory, you could do this:

```
dir2slideshow -n "Thanksgiving 2009" <Your images directory>
```

dvd-slideshow gives you full control over every image or effect individually.  For example:

```
dvd-slideshow [-n <slideshow name>] [-o <output directory>] [-b <background jpeg>] [-a <audiofile1> -a <audiofile2> -a <audiofileN>] [-p] [-L] [-H] [-mp2] [-r] [-smp] -f <input text file>
```

The -f specifies the commands that provide all the instructions to the program.

The finished product are all the files you need to provide to a standard burner to make a dvd.  There are several [simple examples](http://dvd-slideshow.sourceforge.net/wiki/Simple_Example) of the  to get you started - like this one:

```
# simple example with fades
# instead of specifying the background image on the command-line
# it's often easier to do it in this text file:
# background:duration:subtitle:image
# a duration of 0 means to set the image, but don't display it.
 background:0::background.jpg
# Titles are put in the center:
 title:5:My title
 background:1
# The titlebar type of title has two titles, one on top and one lower:
 titlebar:5:My top title:My lower title
 background:1
#  there are simple transitions that you can use:
# fadein, fadeout, and crossfade. They all fade to/from whatever
# background you're using.  Syntax is:
# fadein:duration:subtitle
# you can add a subtitle during the transition, but it's optional
# use a backslash to escape a colon ':' in the subtitles.
# use '\n' to force a newline (only two subtitle lines supported now).
 fadein:2
 picture1.jpg:4:Picture 1 is so cool\:\nI can't believe how cool it really is.
# fadeout is similar:
# fadeout:duration:subtitle
 fadeout:2:Fading out
# it's possible to specify a new title slide in the middle of the slideshow:
 fadein:1
 titlebar:4::Panoramas  # note this just has the bottom title specified.
# crossfade works similar to fadein/fadeout
# crossfade:duration:subtitle
 crossfade:1
 pano.jpg:4:Cool panorama picture
# now let's change the background color:
# syntax is background:duration:subtitle:image
# where you can use "black" or "white"  or "#RRGGBB
# as the image name also.
 background:1::#11a004
# or
 background:1::black
 picture1.jpg:4:Picture 1 is so cool.  I can't believe how cool it really is.
 crossfade:3
 picture2.jpg:3
# it often looks nice to end the slideshow with a fadeout to the
# background instead of just stopping the video quickly:
 fadeout:2
 background:2:This is the background
# note that the background is black now...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use a program from Magix called Photostory.  It costs about $40, but it is extremely easy to use.  You can add music, transitions, and dvd title screens to your project.  I have made 3 wedding videos with this software and they came out perfect.  You have the option to make them for PC or use on a regular DVD Player.